# Returns and line breaks disrupt regex results

Tags: php, regex

I am currently using:

```
preg_match("/(.*)On\s+(Sun|Sat|Fri|Thu|Wed|Tue|Mon),\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d?\d,\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d?\d:\d\d\s+[AP]M,/i", $to, $end);
```

It works great for:

```
$string = "I need to match this. On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 9:23 AM, Prov";
```

But not for:

```
$string = "I need to match this. 

On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 9:23 AM, Prov";
```

The returns in $string2 don't allow for a match. Can I change something in my preg_match so that returns don't disrupt my results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `/s` modifier to allow the dot (`.`) to also match newlines:

```
preg_match("/(.*)On\s+(Sun|Sat|Fri|Thu|Wed|Tue|Mon),\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d?\d,\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d?\d:\d\d\s+[AP]M,/si", $to, $end);
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot '.' character [does not match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) newline.